# Space not releasing after database shrinking MSSQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have an MS-SQL database around 45 GB. mdf file size is 45 GB. I have deleted one table that is around 20 GB, but still the mdf file size is the same 45 GB. I've tried shrinking the mdf file, but nothing is happening. Would there be any impact on the database with shrinking?

It's my production DB.

Thanks

Comment: Shrinking your database file is normally not a good idea; it can cause some big index fragmentation. Why do you need to shrink the database? Storage is cheap and 20GB is nothing in storage terms.

Comment: [Here's a good explanation of why you shouldn't shrink your databases](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/whats-bad-shrinking-databases-dbcc-shrinkdatabase/)

Comment: @Larnu, Thank you for your reply. o think you are right. i should have to purchase Space.

Comment: Did you shrink your data or file?

Comment: @AliBahrami yes data file only.